# Setting precision for RR in the NTL library

Tags: floating-point

I am using the RR class in the NTL library. I set the precision to 128 since I need higher precision for my computations in the program. From the documentation for RR, I see that it offers from min 53 bits and max upto word size of the machine but when I print the values with cout, it only has 9 decimal digits.

When I print the mantissa and exponent part separately, I find that the 9 decimal digits printed is after rounding. Is it because of the cout?

Answer (score 0):

just use `RR::SetOutputPrecision(d);` to increase the precision of the output, where `d` is the number of bits you want your answer to be represented in.